# MusixTex, \sk does not work

Tags: music, musixtex

I'm trying to make an extract with all clefs used to show the different position of the same note. And I did this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
      \nobarnumbers
      \setclef18
      \startextract
        \setdoublebar
        \setclef16\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef15\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef14\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef13\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef12\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef11\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef10\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar
      \endextract
    \end{music}
    ~
\end{document}
```

Which produce:

[image: Music clefs]

As we can see, there is no space between the first clef and the first note, where as there is space between every other clefs and notes. While I added the same line (`\sk`) for each clefs. I set the first clef to the empty one, and then changed it to the bass one to make all clefs the same size.

Quote from the [MusiXTeX documentation](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf) (page 74):

> Clef changes initiated with the `\setclef` command have several features in common. When activated after the beginning of the piece, the printed symbol is smaller than the normal one used at the beginning of the piece.

My question:
How can I get a space between the first clef and note?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem occurs because of the clef change in the beginning. You should use the first clef instead of making it invisible. You can adjust the size to the smaller version by using

```
\setclef16
\setbassclefsymbol1\smallbassclef
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
      \nobarnumbers
      \setclef16
      \setbassclefsymbol1\smallbassclef
      \startextract
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef15\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef14\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef13\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef12\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef11\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar

        \changecontext%
        \setclef10\Changeclefs%
        \sk%
        \notes \qa c \en \setdoublebar
      \endextract
    \end{music}
    ~
\end{document}
```

[image: result]